# Runtime Strategy on drools kie server is always showing singleton

Tags: drools, kie-workbench, kie-server

I am am deploying my kjar onto kie server container using kie workbench.  The kie deployment descriptor has "runtime-strategy" set to "PER_REQUEST".  However, when kie server container is finally created, it is showing "runtime-strategy" as "SINGLETON" always.  The behavior is also reflecting "SINGLETON".

Please let me know of a solution to this.

Comment: Can you please update your question with what version of Kie server and Workbench do you use?

What steps did you do to deploy kjar?

Comment: kie-wb-distribution-wars-7.0.0.Beta1-wildfly10.war

Answer (score 0):

I see the same behavior with kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-tomcat7.war. For some reason the "Save" button is disabled(attached screenshot)[Execution Server Page : Drools Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW8d1.png)

I am logged in as admin just to make sure its not an authorization issue. Thoughts on what could be the issue?

Comment: I experience the same behavior with 7.5.0 Final. Any chance someone can recommend a workaround via API or how to fix this? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the drools google group: This is a UI only issue. Can be confirmed by making a REST call to the Kie Server.

More details : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RHBPMS-4373